# How to add hyperlink list item on JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, list

I'm having trouble with json. here is my list.js.
anyway i'm using json2html.js html template engine.

```
var mylist = [
{ "name": "Pizza", "pic":"pizza.jpg", "type":"Food", "desc":"Bla bla","page":"pizza.html"},
{ "name": "Donut", "pic":"Donut.jpg", "type":"Food", "desc":"Bla bla.","page":"donut.html"},];

var rule_list = 
    {"tag": "li", "children": [
        {"tag":"a","href":"src/$(page)",},
        {"tag":"img","src":"res/i/${pic}","html":""},
        {"tag":"div","class":"li-title","html":"${name}","children":[
        {"tag":"p","html":"${type}","children":[
              {"tag":"br","html":"${desc}"}
            ]}
        ]}
]};

var content_list = json2html.transform(mylist,rule_list);
document.write('<ul id="search_list" class="listview">'+ content_list + '</ul>');
```

and this is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> test </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/json2html.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
</head><body onload="loaded()">
   <div id="mycontent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="fb-res.js"></script>
   </div>
</body>
```

How can i add `<a href="...html">` for each `<li>` that generated from json? i've tried above and the link is not appear.

Sorry for my bad english.
Thanks guys

Comment: Have you tried my code? I think it works...

Comment: still not works. nothing happened. i've tried for couple hours. Anyway, i've edited my code above and i hope you understand what i mean. thanks :-)

Comment: you have invalid `rule_list` remove the last `]};`, here is the [working version](http://jsfiddle.net/d3jbsh07)

Comment: wow thank you, but hyperlink still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the simple hack, so simply. works like a charm and suddenly i laughed.
Simple solution is, we have to add some `a.divclass` and make it clickable. put it in json.

The CSS

```
a.page-link{
  z-index:2; /* Must above the <li> */
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  min-height:95px; /* depend on <li> height */
  height:100%; /* use it when each <li> have different height */
}
```

The JSON (Use json2html template engine)

```
var mylist = [
    { "name": "Pizza", "pic":"pizza.jpg", "type":"Food", "desc":"Bla bla.", "link":"src/pizza.html"},
    { "name": "Donut", "pic":"donut.jpg", "type":"Food", "desc":"Bla bla.", "link":"src/donut.html"},
];

var rule_list = 
        {"tag": "li", "children": [
            {"tag":"a","href":"${link}","class":"page-link"},
            {"tag":"img","src":"res/i/${pic}","html":""},
            {"tag":"div","class":"li-title","html":"${name}","children":[
            {"tag":"p","html":"${type}","children":[
                  {"tag":"br","html":"${desc}"}
                ]}
            ]}  
        ]};

var content_list = json2html.transform(mylist,rule_list);
$('#page').html('<ul id="search_list" class="listview">'+ content_list + '</ul>');

document.write(''+content_list+'');
```

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> test </title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/json2html.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
</head><body onload="loaded()">
   <div id="mycontent">
<script type="text/javascript" src="fb-res.js"></script>
   </div>
</body>
```

Hope this simple hack can help everybody that have same problem with me. How to create hyperlink for each json data.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you can do it like that:

```
// Add the list to the body
var content_list = json2html.transform(mylist,rule_list);
var list = $("<ul />").attr('id', 'search_list').addClass("listview").html(content_list);
$("body").append(list);

// Add links
$.each($("#search_list").children(), function(i, item) {
    var link = $("<a />").attr("href", mylist[i].name.toLowerCase() + ".html");
    $(this).append(link);
});
```

The `$("#search_list").children()` method find all *li* elements in the list and append the appropriate link.

Comment: still not working. Where i place that code? I've try it, place into html or js. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited my post, you have to place it at the end of the js file. However, it will be better to create the search_list directly in your html page and append the content_list in JavaScript...

Comment: hard to solve and understand. Still not working. :-(

Answer (score 0):

FYI your transform is wrong, change $(page) to ${page} and it should work fine

```
var rule_list = 
{"tag": "li", "children": [
    {"tag":"a","href":"src/${page}",},
    {"tag":"img","src":"res/i/${pic}","html":""},
    {"tag":"div","class":"li-title","html":"${name}","children":[
    {"tag":"p","html":"${type}","children":[
          {"tag":"br","html":"${desc}"}
        ]}
    ]}
]};
```